# Reading HTML into R. Finding Proper CSS

Tags: r

I am trying to web scrape news data into R from the financial website Finviz. I am trying to parse the html file so it is readable. But I cannot seem to find the proper CSS that would allow me to view the news in a readable format in R (td/ tr??). I want to be able to read the news headline in R in a format that is readable.

```
library(rvest)
finviz_news<- html("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl")
news_formated=html_nodes("td",finviz_news)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the news table? Use your browser's web dev tools to figure out where that is. If you're going to do this a lot then get familiar with your browser's inspector, or some clicky tool that can get you the id of an element. I actually just used my ad-blocker's query tool to see what the table was (you can block elements using the same css selector queries as in `rvest`)

So that told me the news table element has an id of "news-table", so I can do this:

```
> d = html_table(html_nodes(finviz_news,"#news-table"))[[1]]
> head(d)
                   X1
1 Dec-17-15 03:13PM  
2           03:13PM  
3           02:50PM  
4           02:39PM  
5           02:10PM  
6           02:01PM  
                                                                                  X2
1                               Apple names Jeff Williams as chief operating officer
2                                         Key iPhone Sale Is an Upgrade at Bloomberg
3                                   Pleased as Pie by Apple's Latest Executive Moves
4                         Apple supplier's light forecast exacerbates iPhone jitters
5 [$$] Apple Kremlinology: Why Operations Got a Promotion at The Wall Street Journal
6                                            This man could be the next CEO of Apple
```

So now `d` is a data frame of that table.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried some app I download called SelectGadget but it gave me the name "td tr". Maybe its because I clicked on a specific article rather than highlighting the entire box?? I will double check. But for future reference, how do you know the CSS from looking only at the HTML?? Does it start with id=<CSS NAME HERE> ? Because when I searched and found #news-table, i found id=news-table, there was no pound # sign in there.

Comment: HTML elements (like <table>, <p> etc) can have an "ID" (which should be unique in a document) and a "class" - many elements can be the same class. If you have the ID of an element you can get it with `#news-table`. If you want to get all elements with a given class you use dots: `.alerts`. Read up on CSS Selectors online for more.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to use the function `XML::readHTMLTable` in R. To demonstrate, suppose that you want to parse the first table on the page. This could be accomplished with the following code.

```
library(XML)
aapl <- readHTMLTable("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl")

# financial highlights
fin_hl <- aapl[[4]]
fin_hl <- fin_hl[14:nrow(fin_hl),]
df <- data.frame(Category=character(0), Value=character(0))
for(i in 1:(ncol(fin_hl)/2)) {
  tmp <- fin_hl[,((i-1)*2+1):(i*2)]
  names(tmp) <- c("Category","Value")
  df <- rbind(df, tmp)
}
row.names(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
head(df)

 #   Category       Value
 # 1      Index DJIA S&P500
 # 2 Market Cap     620.76B
 # 3     Income      53.39B
 # 4      Sales     233.72B
 # 5    Book/sh       21.14
 # 6    Cash/sh        7.46
```

In this case, the html tables are stored in the list object `aapl`. Then, getting your information is just a matter of selecting the program `data.frame` from `aapl` and parsing this `data.frame`.